# iOS Keeping section titles anchored in Grouped Table Style

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a grouped table view to display items on a view controller.

I want anchor the section's title just like it happens with the plani styled table.

How could I do that?

Comment: When you say "anchor" what do you mean? Could you post some images to show us.

Comment: I mean like on Address Book for the iPhone. When you start scrolling the list on letter `A` it will always show `A` on the top until you start scrolling the contacts in the `B` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I know what you mean, my answer is no, you don't think you will be able to do that in a simple way. You might be able to do that with some workarounds using custom `UITableViewCells` and custom `UIView's` as the section's titles. I guess that way you could achieve that.

Comment: Again, if that's really needed you can try to achieve that.